# Spotify for RPI

Tags: raspbian

Spotify is a versatile and open platform for music worldwide. It is heavy on encryption and very high on CPU usage.

Anyone aware of a yum/apt-get Spotify version for **RPI** running raspbian? Even without GUI, just command player version will be fine.

I understand that as of May 2015 *libspotify* is officially deprecated by Spotify and is no longer actively maintained, *Libspotify* was the base for many products, and now Spotify look only to sdk iPhones (IOS) and Android.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the answers!

Really `mopidy` made the cut. As most packages is not just plug and play but is very close to that. I will make the installation as brief as possible and it will work fine.

## Ingredients:

- Raspberry PI running Wheezy (may also work with Jessie)
- PuTTY or similar remote SSH client.
- A paid Spotify account.
- External speakers, perhaps an USB sound card.

## Pre-Installation

Before going into the install, make sure the RPI is ready to play music.

First, activate ipv6.

```
modprobe ipv6
echo ipv6 | tee -a /etc/modules
```

if needed, you can force sound on the analog connector instead of HDMI

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

test the sound to confirm your setting is working.

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

## Installation

Note: Either prefix your commands with `sudo` or just do a 'permanent' `sudo -iE` before you start.

first, get the KEY from `mopidy`

```
wget -q -O - https://apt.mopidy.com/mopidy.gpg | apt-key add -
```

Add the source list, this is on wheezy.

```
wget -q -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mopidy.list https://apt.mopidy.com/wheezy.list
```

or this for Jessie

```
wget -q -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mopidy.list https://apt.mopidy.com/jessie.list
```

and now, add the new items, install mopidy and the Spotify extension

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mopidy
apt-get install mopidy-spotify
```

if you are working as root, use this .conf file

```
/root/.config/mopidy/mopidy.conf
```

Otherwise edit it on your home config.   Search the '[Spotify]' section remove the '#' remarks from the line and edit a few items:

```
[spotify]
username = alice
password = mysecret
```

remove the comments also on the [mpd] section, make explicit that we are not using [local] and [files] adding 'enabled = false'.

## you are done!!

to test, open a console version and install a client:

```
apt-get install ncmpcpp
```

then, form another puTTY run

```
ncmpcpp
```

Good listening!

Comment: Does mopidy-spotify support offline playback?

Comment: The instruction above assumes one starts mopidy as a user. I'm not sure how to provide user's config for a system service?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Volumio](https://volumio.org) [Note: currently returning an empty page for me so they might have an issue on their servers, so you might have to check back later]. Volumio is a full OS with an audio playback server controlled via a web interface, and runs on the RPi. I use it on an RPi model B. It has a Spotify client, but you need a premium Spotify account for it (won't work with the "free" Spotify). I've written my own custom Pandora server for use in Volumio - but that code is not yet ready for primetime (needs a webUI :)).

**On Second Thought**: This might no longer work as per your *libspotify* comment .... I'm not a Spotify user myself so I cannot check.

Answer (score 2):

[Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) with extensions allows you to stream from cloud services such as Spotify (and others as well as local files obviously). Packages should be available for Raspian including dependencies, but other than that it can be installed from source and is running on python2.7 ([see here](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/raspberrypi/#raspberrypi-installation)).

I take it that the developers are aware that libspotify is officially deprecated but worry not too much as it still works for now ([see here](https://discuss.mopidy.com/t/libspotify-deprecated/751)). They seem to expect spotify to come up with a solution due to its use in numerous hardware platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Spotify don't have client for Raspberry as well as for any Linux ARM device.
But you can use x86 emulations to run **original Spotify Client** on RPi.

1. Install ExaGear Desktop, which allow to run x86 software on Raspberry (note that ExaGear isn't free and you have to obtain the license)

   ```
   tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-exagear.sh ubuntu-1404
   ```
2. Run ExaGear

   ```
   exagear
   ```
3. Add the Spotify repository signing key

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
   ```
4. Add the Spotify repository

   ```
   echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
   ```
5. Install Spotify

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install spotify-client
    sudo apt-get install libxss1
   ```
6. Now you can run Spotify from Start Menu

[image: Run Spotify on Raspberry Pi]

Instruction is based on [this post](https://eltechs.com/run-spotify-on-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: It costs 18€ and is tied to the SDCARD.. please reflect this in your post. Not a place for commercial software.