# Running spotify on Raspberry PI

Tags: audio

I have seen other questions here on how to do this but most of them suggest the solution of using The raspberry Pi streaming server solution. But what I want to do is simply to run the software alongside other software (e.g. Kodi, a normal internet browser etc).

My Rasp Pi will run (Broke the SD card, waiting for a new one) Raspbian. And the official unsuported spotify build for linux is a Debian package. Will it work out of the box?

Comment: https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-spotify has very recent commits, at least that suggests that there is hope.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/spotify-for-rpi?s=1|1.6905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The current Spotify package is compiled for x86 architecture processors. Unfortunately the Pi has an ARM architecture processor. These are fundamentally incompatible. You'll need to use one of the server options.

Comment: So there is no way in actually running the spotify gui on my rasp Pi?

Comment: There is, at the time of writing, no way to run any software written by Spotify on the Raspberry Pi. There are several solutions available (as you've already noted) which access Spotify's catalogue and audio data, but are not in themselves provided by Spotify.