# Qobuz or Tidal streaming on Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, audio, streaming, audio-playback

This question discusses [Spotify for RPI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/spotify-for-rpi), but not other streaming services.

How would it be possible to use the likes of Qobuz or Tidal on the Pi 2? Especially in the context of audiophile distros like RuneAudio or Volumio... I was suggested that it would be possible to set the Pi as a DLNA node, and thus stream services like Tidal from an Android device to the Pi and then out to my headphones, but I have no idea where one would start.

Answer (score 1):

For Tidal one solution is to use [Pi MusicBox](http://www.pimusicbox.com/). It uses Mopidy which has an extension for Tidal support: [mopidy-tidal](https://github.com/mones88/mopidy-tidal).

> Tidal Backend plugin for Mopidy
>
> Tidal music service integration