# Stream music from PC (Win10) to pi (BIG NOOB)

Tags: raspbian, audio, wireless, ethernet

Hi i have a problem that i would be **extremly happy** to solve:

I want to make my sound (If possible only spotify sound) go from my pc go to the raspberry pi and from the pi to a jackstick to my stereo.

I have a Raspberry pi with freshly installed raspbian on :) I have a cable going from the router to my Rapberry pi And im running wireless on my PC(i can use cable if needed to make it work) But the project was about getting it to run wireless :)

**BTW** im pretty nooby to this soo. Sry for the "Wierd" english ;)

Im pretty sure it's a raspberry pi 2B
[image: Like this :D]

Comment: I think you might find this post: [Spotify for RPI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/spotify-for-rpi) useful.

Comment: @Darth Vader Well i dont have "Paid" spotify ;( Buw i will give it a try thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use bluestacks on your pc and get the app raspicast of google play if you only have a pc BUT if you have a phone it is even easier.

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-chromecast/

Comment: This answer would've been much better if you took your time to explain **how** to use those things you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Update: I went on runeaudio.com and downloaded their software and **it works** abseloutly perfect for my use. Extremly easy to setup aswell and a lot of **cool features!**

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.